# Циркумфикс -- способ словообразования

Tags: словообразование, терминология

Как стоит называть словообразовательную модель, при которой к основе присоединяется циркумфикс — циркумфиксация? Тогда способ — циркумфиксальный?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Угу.

**[Университетское издание](https://www.hse.ru/mirror/pubs/lib/data/access/ram/ticket/88/1482471330e5822892fcef59b3684b548d9b44f678/paper_MSCL2007.pdf)** глаголет:

"Циркумфиксация — явление, засвидетельствованное во многих языках".

"В работе предлагается композициональный подход, согласно которому значение циркумфиксального комплекса складывается из значений его частей — префиксального и постфиксального компонентов, однако это значение является идиоматизированным: префикс и постфикс одновременно присоединяются к исходному глаголу. Наконец, определяется, **какие префиксально-постфиксальные глагольные образования в русском уже можно считать циркумфиксальными**".

"Поскольку в русском глагольном словообразовании имеется только один постфикс (-ся), то, вероятно, если циркумфиксы существуют в русском языке, то -ся будет участвовать в их образовании.

Среди тех способов словообразования возвратных глаголов, которые выделяет Янко-Триницкая 1962, наибольший интерес представляет префиксально-постфиксальный (раз-бежать-ся, за-играть-ся, до-сидеть-ся), т. к. именно он удовлетворяет определению, предложенному в ЛЭС 1990.

Не все префиксально-постфиксальные глаголы имеют статус циркумфиксальных. Так, не являются циркумфиксальными глаголы, морфологически и семантически деривированные от соответствующих префиксальных и постфиксальных (испрясться: испрясть + ся, ис + прясться).

Однако глаголы, не употребляющиеся отдельно с префиксом или с постфиксом, правомочно назвать циркумфиксальными: намолчаться (*намолчать, *молчаться), извороваться (*изворовать, *вороваться в непассивном прочтении) и др.

Если глагол не удовлетворяет морфологическому критерию (сформулированному в предыдущем абзаце), который является, как видно, достаточным для признания циркумфиксального статуса глагола, то следует прибегнуть к семантическому критерию :

Префиксально-постфиксальный комплекс будет называться циркумфиксом, а глаголы, его содержащие, — циркумфиксальными, если значение комплекса композиционально выводимо из значений его частей; причем важно, чтобы его префиксальный компонент имел семантику, отличную от семантики префикса в однокоренном префиксальном глаголе.

Например, значение глагола запрыгаться ‘увлекшись прыганием, утомиться’ не выводимо из значений префикса за- в глаголе запрыгать ‘начать прыгать’ и постфикса -ся, по всей видимости, выражающего рефлексивное значение. Префикс за- имеет такую же семантику, что и в глаголе загонять ‘довести кого/что-нибудь до нежелательного состояния’.

[А также](http://www.booksite.ru/fulltext/1/001/008/078/367.htm):

> Инвентаризация и исследование способов, применяемых в разных языках
> для выражения тех или иных значений в пределах словоформ; разработка
> теории таких способов, называемых морфологическими. Известны 5
> основных классов морфологических способов, которые распадаются на
> сегментные, т. е. связанные с морфами (а-г), и супрасегментные, т. е.
> связанные только с просодическими морфологическими единицами (д): а)
> сложение, в том числе корне-, осново- и словосложение (рус.
> «блок-схема», «жёлто-бурый», франц. un rendez-vous — «свидание»,
> буквально «явите вас»); б) аффиксация: префиксация (рус. «посильнее»),
> постфиксация (рус.«чита-тель», «нос-ы»), инфиксация [лат. vi-n-c(o) —
> «побеждаю» при vic(ī) — «я победил»], интерфиксация (рус.
> «бетон-о-мешалка»), **циркумфиксация [нем. gesag-t — «сказанный» при
> sag(en) — «говорить»]** и трансфиксация (араб. r-a-sm — «рисунок» при
> r-u-s-ū-m — «рисунки»); в) модификация (изменение означающего морфы):
> чередование (англ. tooth — «зуб» при teeth — «зубы») и повтор
> (индонез. karangan — «статья» при karangan-karangan — «статьи»); г)
> конверсия (изменение синтактики морфы, т. е. её сочетаемости): англ.
> (to) cook — «варить» при (the) cook — «повар»; д) супрафиксация
> (выражение значения определённым просодическим явлением — тоном,
> ударением и т. п.).

---

Н-да. Мы университетов не кончали, простой постсоветский редактор мы, но вот етое

> то, вероятно, если циркумфиксы существуют в русском языке, то -ся
> будет участвовать

явно речь не мальчика, но мужа.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, способ словообразования с помощью циркумфикса стоит отнести к приставочно-суффиксальным. Словообразовательную модель - по аналогии с суффиксной - можно назвать циркумфиксной.